# cannot update PHP on mac osx 10.9

Tags: php, bash, osx-mavericks

I downloaded and installed php 5.6 from php-osx.liip.ch and also edited the path to /usr/local/bin in /.bash_profile.

I am getting php version 5.6.19 in terminal, but when I execute `phpinfo();` I still see the previous 5.4 version

also the php info shows that the php.ini lies in /etc directory

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is 3 months old, this just happened to me yesterday with the same installer (php-osx.liip.ch), so here's my solution.

In my case, the apache configuration (httpd.conf) was pointing to the old php extension:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

When it should be this:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
```

Your path should be the same as mine. My httpd.conf is on /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

After editing httpd, restart apache and phpinfo() should return the correct version.